# Typescript generic service

Tags: angular, generics, typescript, service

I'm new to typescript and angular2/4 and I'm building a single app that have two basic entities which is Car and Driver and all I do is to list them with an API call.

The problem I'm facing is that I have code redundancy for each CarService and DriverService, and I might have the same code for other entities service.

The implementation is following so far, skipping other methods for ilustration :

```
@Injectable()
export class CarService  {

private actionUrl: string;
private headers: Headers;

constructor(private _http: Http, private _configuration: Configuration) {

    // Getting API URL and specify the root
    this.actionUrl = _configuration.serverWithApiUrl + 'Car/';

    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
}

// Function to get all Cars - API CALL: /
public GetAll = (): Observable<Car[]> => {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <Car[]>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

// Function to get a Car by specific id - API CALL: /:id
public GetSingle = (id: number): Observable<Car> => {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl + id)
        .map((response: Response) => <Car>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

// Function to add a Car - API CALL: /create
public Add = (newCar: Car): Observable<Car> => {
    return this._http.post(this.actionUrl + '/create', JSON.stringify(newCar), { headers: this.headers })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

// Function to update a Car - API CALL: /
public Update = (id: number, CarToUpdate: Car): Observable<Car> => {
    return this._http.put(this.actionUrl + id, JSON.stringify(CarToUpdate), { headers: this.headers })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

// Function to delete a Car - API CALL: /:id
public Delete = (id: number): Observable<Response> => {
    return this._http.delete(this.actionUrl + id)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

// Function to throw errors
private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

What only change with the DriverService is the `Car/` at the end of the url and the data type in `Observable<Car[]>` and the response.

I would like to know what is the best way to avoid this with a generic service and how to do it in Typescript.

Comment: why even have services for this? why not just use the http service as the generic one?

Comment: alternatively you might want to look into the ngx-resource library. https://github.com/troyanskiy/ngx-resource

Comment: I have more than one function in my service, but for simplicity I hide the others calls.

Comment: don't, they might be relevant. :)

Comment: I updated the question with the full service, the driver and other entities service, is the same, only url and data type will change, so thats why I thought of a generic service but I have no idea how to implement it and I couldn't find a complete and well explained way to do it with a service

Comment: @toskv: it might be easier to handle errors inside one single service than in several components (in order to redirect to an error page, for example). And storing an hard-coded URL in several components does not sound like a good idea : if the API endpoint changes, you'll need to make search and replace by hand.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can create an abstract generic class and two children class that inherits from it :

**abstract class:**

```js
export abstract class AbstractRestService<T> {
  constructor(protected _http: Http, protected actionUrl:string){
  }

  getAll():Observable<T[]> {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl).map(resp=>resp.json() as T[]);
  }
  getOne(id:number):Observable<T> {
    return this._http.get(`${this.actionUrl}${id}`).map(resp=>resp.json() as T);
  }
}
```

**driver service class**

```js
@Injectable()
export class DriverService extends AbstractRestService<Driver> {
  constructor(http:Http,configuration:Configuration){
    super(http,configuration.serverWithApiUrl+"Driver/");
  }
}
```

**car service class**

```js
@Injectable()
export class CarService extends AbstractRestService<Car> {
  constructor(http:Http,configuration:Configuration) {
    super(http,configuration.serverWithApiUrl+"Car/");
  }
}
```

Note that only the concrete classes are marked as `@Injectable()` and should be declared inside a module while the abstract one should not.

**update for Angular 4+**

`Http` class being deprecated in favor of `HttpClient`, you can change the abstract class to something like that:

```js
export abstract class AbstractRestService<T> {
  constructor(protected _http: HttpClient, protected actionUrl:string){
  }

  getAll():Observable<T[]> {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl) as Observable<T[]>;
  }

  getOne(id:number):Observable<T> {
    return this._http.get(`${this.actionUrl}${id}`) as Observable<T>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes thats more precisely what I was looking as an implementation.
And then my question would be how to call the `getAll()` in one of the subclass ?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry... from where do you want to call `getAll()` ?

Comment: I mean if I call the `getAll()` of the CarService in a component, it will be something like this : `this._carService.GetAll().subscribe((data: Car[])...` right ? I will not have a problem of Data type right ?

Comment: Oh sorry I made a mistake inside my code, I edited. No, you shouldn't have any problem as the abstract class is generic, but concrete ones are not. `CarService` handles `Car` and `Car[]`, while `DriverService` handles `Driver` and `Driver[]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer its more clear and I have a good understanding of how I'm gonna implement it now.
One last question, so in the providers in the app.module, I'll have to put all services ? The entities service only ? or the abstract service only ?

Comment: Only the two concrete services (those marked as `@Injectable()`).

Comment: Is there any reason the base class is abstract?  It's not in the example.

Comment: as there is an `actionurl` property, you could not use that abstract service except by setting that property on the fly.

Comment: Note: When using Angular 2+ use `HttpClient` instead of `HTTP`

Comment: @danger89 *Angular 4+

Comment: Can You extend the answer with the Configuration?

Comment: @n00dl3 Can you please add complete example in GitHub with Configuration ?

Answer (score 5):

Below is a basic example built on **Angular 7** and **RxJS 6**.

`ApiResponse<T>` represents any server response. Server must have the same structure and return it whatever happens:

```
export class ApiResponse<T> {
  constructor() {
    this.errors = [];
  }
  data: T;
  errors: ApiError[];
  getErrorsText(): string {
    return this.errors.map(e => e.text).join(' ');
  }
  hasErrors(): boolean {
    return this.errors.length > 0;
  }
}

export class ApiError { code: ErrorCode; text: string; }

export enum ErrorCode {
  UnknownError = 1,
  OrderIsOutdated = 2,
  ...
}
```

Generic service:

```
export class RestService<T> {
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
       'Accept': 'application/json'})
  };
  private _apiEndPoint: string = environment.apiEndpoint;
  constructor(private _url: string, private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<ApiResponse<T[]>> {
    return this.mapAndCatchError(
      this._http.get<ApiResponse<T[]>>(this._apiEndPoint + this._url
         , this.httpOptions)
    );
  }
  get(id: number): Observable<ApiResponse<T>> {
    return this.mapAndCatchError(
      this._http.get<ApiResponse<T>>(`${this._apiEndPoint + this._url}/${id}`
         , this.httpOptions)
    );
  }
  add(resource: T): Observable<ApiResponse<number>> {
    return this.mapAndCatchError(
      this._http.post<ApiResponse<number>>(
        this._apiEndPoint + this._url,
        resource,
        this.httpOptions)
    );
  }
  // update and remove here...

  // common method
  makeRequest<TData>(method: string, url: string, data: any)
                                    : Observable<ApiResponse<TData>> {
    let finalUrl: string = this._apiEndPoint + url;
    let body: any = null;
    if (method.toUpperCase() == 'GET') {
      finalUrl += '?' + this.objectToQueryString(data);
    }
    else {
      body = data;
    }
    return this.mapAndCatchError<TData>(
      this._http.request<ApiResponse<TData>>(
        method.toUpperCase(),
        finalUrl,
        { body: body, headers: this.httpOptions.headers })
    );
  }

  /////// private methods
  private mapAndCatchError<TData>(response: Observable<ApiResponse<TData>>)
                                         : Observable<ApiResponse<TData>> {
    return response.pipe(
      map((r: ApiResponse<TData>) => {
        var result = new ApiResponse<TData>();
        Object.assign(result, r);
        return result;
      }),
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        var result = new ApiResponse<TData>();
        // if err.error is not ApiResponse<TData> e.g. connection issue
        if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent || err.error instanceof ProgressEvent) {
          result.errors.push({ code: ErrorCode.UnknownError, text: 'Unknown error.' });
        }
        else {
          Object.assign(result, err.error)
        }
        return of(result);
      })
    );
  }

  private objectToQueryString(obj: any): string {
    var str = [];
    for (var p in obj)
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      }
    return str.join("&");
  }
}
```

then you can derive from `RestService<T>`:

```
export class OrderService extends RestService<Order> {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) { super('order', http); }
}
```

and use it:

```
this._orderService.getAll().subscribe(res => {
  if (!res.hasErrors()) {
    //deal with res.data : Order[]
  }
  else {
    this._messageService.showError(res.getErrorsText());
  }
});
// or
this._orderService.makeRequest<number>('post', 'order', order).subscribe(r => {
  if (!r.hasErrors()) {
    //deal with r.data: number
  }
  else
    this._messageService.showError(r.getErrorsText());
});
```

You can redesign `RestService<T>.ctor` and inject `RestService<Order>` directly instead of declaring and injection `OrderService`.

It looks like `RxJS 6` doesn't allow to rethrow/return typed errors. For this reason `RestService<T>` catches all errors and returns them within strongly typed `ApiResponse<T>`. The calling code should check `ApiResponse<T>.hasErrors()` instead of catching errors on `Observable<T>`

Answer (score 3):

Have a base service for your app.

With `get` `post` and `delete` methods with your `base URL` attached.

```
export class HttpServiceBase {

    HOST_AND_ENDPOINT_START : string = 'you/rD/efa/ult/Url' ;
    public getWebServiceDataWithPartialEndpoint(remainingEndpoint: string): Observable<Response> {

        if (!remainingEndpoint) {
            console.error('HttpServiceBase::getWebServiceDataWithPartialEndpoint - The supplied remainingEndpoint was invalid');
            console.dir(remainingEndpoint);
        }

        console.log('GET from : ' , this.HOST_AND_ENDPOINT_START + remainingEndpoint);
        return this.http.get(
            this.HOST_AND_ENDPOINT_START + remainingEndpoint

        );
    }
```

This a useful implementation as it allows you to easily debug WS calls - all calls end up coming from the base.

`HOST_AND_ENDPOINT_START` can be overriden by any module that you want to extend the base service.

Lets pretend your endpoint is something like:
`/myapp/rest/`

And you want to implement a `HttpSearchBase` you can simply extend `HttpServiceBase` and override `HOST_AND_ENDPOINT_START` with something like:

`/myapp/rest/search`

Example `CarDriverService`

```
@Injectable()
export class CarDriverService extends HttpServiceBase{

    //here we are requesting a different API
    HOST_AND_ENDPOINT_START : string = '/myapp/rest/vehicle/;
    getAllCars() : Observable<Car[]>{
    return this.getWebServiceDataWithPartialEndpoint('/Car')
           .map(res => <Car[]>res.json())
    }

    getAllDrivers(){
    return this.getWebServiceDataWithPartialEndpoint('/Driver')
    }

    addNewDriver(driver: Driver){
    return this.postWebServiceDataWithPartialEndpoint('/Driver/',driver)
    }


}
```

Comment: I see the logic behind and its kind of what I wanted.
But in this casefor example, in CarDriverService to getAllCars() and map it to my data type, all I have to do is `return this.getWebServiceDataWithPartialEndpoint('/Car').map((response: Response) => <Car[]>response.json())` ?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to include mapping - i have updated the `getAllCars` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DanielCooke